# Create a Dataframe from list of Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Please help me creating a Dataframe from list of dictionaries

```
Dataset = [{'A': ' X1'}, {'B': ' Y1'}, {'A': ' X2'}, {'B': ' Y2'}, {'A': ' X3'}, {'B': ' Y3'}, {'C': ' Z3'}]
```

The output should be:

[image: The output should be:]

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and pandas' [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method. The trick is to use the orient parameter and transpose the dataframe in order to handle the missing values in the C column

```
def cast_to_dataframe(_ds):
    """
    Cast the given list of dictionaries to one dataframe

    :param _ds: List of dictionaries
    :return: DataFrame
    """

    final_dict = defaultdict(list)

    # Iterate through each dictionary in _ds
    for d in _ds:
        for key, value in d.items():
            final_dict[key].append(value)
    # Cast back to dict
    final_dict = dict(final_dict)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_dict, orient='index')

    return df.transpose()

dataset = [{'A': ' X1'}, {'B': ' Y1'}, {'A': ' X2'}, {'B': ' Y2'}, {'A': ' X3'}, {'B': ' Y3'}, {'C': ' Z3'}]

cast_to_dataframe(dataset)
```

Comment: Thank You
The output is a bit different. Z3 is coming in X1 row. The output u are gettng is similar to what i was getting, but the i need Z3 in X3 row.