# DataFrame from list of multiple dictionaries where keys are index and values is column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, defaultdict

I am trying to create a DataFrame with pandas from a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
[{'3600': '12', '7600': '1212343'}, {'0': 0.0, '3600': 0.0, '7200': 0.0, '10800': 0.0, '14400': 0.0, '18000': 0.0, '21600': 0.0, '25200': 116.93828280645994} .... ]
```

My columns is a list of items: `["col1", "col2" ...]`

What I want is the keys of the dicts to be the index, the values of the dicts should fill the columns. In this example:

```
                       col1                  col2
0                       0/NaN                0.0
3600                    12                   0.0
7600                    1212343              NaN
7200                    NaN                  0.0
10800                   NaN                  0.0
18000                   NaN                  0.0
21600                   NaN                  0.0
25200                   NaN                  116.93828280645994
```

So the values of each dictionary basically represent column values. Since the dicts can be of different sizes I need to add NaN.

I thought I had this already figured out with the help here([Create a Dataframe from list of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508852/)) like this:

```
    columns = ["col", "col2" ...]
    df_data = mydataasabove

    final_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for data in df_data:
        for key, value in data.items():
            final_dict[key].append(value)

    final_dict = dict(final_dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_dict, orient='index', columns=columns)
```

But this gives me a df like this:

```
                     col1                     col2
3600                   12                    0.0
7600              1212343                    NaN
0                       0                    NaN
7200                    0                    NaN
10800                   0                    NaN
14400                   0                    NaN
18000                   0                    NaN
21600                   0                    NaN
25200             116.938                    NaN
```

As you can see the values do not correspond correctly to my columns. The output of printing `final_dict` is:

`{'3600': ['12', 0.0], '7600': ['1212343'], '0': [0.0], '7200': [0.0], '10800': [0.0], '14400': [0.0], '18000': [0.0], '21600': [0.0], '25200': [116.93828280645994]}`

I also tried something along the lines with Chainmap:

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ChainMap(*nec_data), orient='index', columns=['col1'])`
but I couldn't add multiple columns.

Maybe someone can lend me a ? It would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(your_dictionary).T` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dictionary, orient='index')`

Comment: @anky, thank you, but this transposes my dictionary, but I need the keys to remain the index.

Comment: @ansev thank you, but as you can see, this is what I am already trying after my loop and it gives me the df which I describe - which unfortunately - populates the df with incorrect values

Comment: @PuneetSingh thank you, but no it doesn't since it doesn't give me the keys as index with the correct column values

Comment: the keys will be the index with that code, can you try? please let me know what you get and how does it differ from what you want

Comment: @anky My apologies, I was trying your suggestion before but specified the kwarg columns and that's why it got switched. Your suggestion does indeed give me the correct df which I want to get, but it doesn't give me the correct column names I want (but it gives me 0,1...). If I specify the columns it gets switched around.... Might you have an idea how to adjust that?

Comment: Figured it out, had to use index instead of columns

Comment: @anky thak you so much for this! If you want to formulate an answer I'd be happy to accept it to give you credit for it!

Comment: hmm, do you mean columns should be `col1` and `col2` instead of 0 and 1? `pd.DataFrame(d).T.rename(columns=lambda x: f"col{x+1}")` ?

Comment: @anky Yes that's exactly what I meant. See my comments above I achieved it by specifying index=["col1", "col2"] instead of columns=.. Thank you very much, really helped me out. As I said above, If you want to formulate an answer I'd be happy to accept it to give you credit for it!

Comment: Okay :) dont specify when you can do dynamic :-)

Comment: Yess agreed :) !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read as a dataframe and transpose , then rename to adjust the column names with the help of `df.rename` and `f-strings`

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.rename(columns=lambda x: f"col{x+1}")
```

---

```
          col1     col2
3600        12        0
7600   1212343      NaN
0          NaN        0
7200       NaN        0
10800      NaN        0
14400      NaN        0
18000      NaN        0
21600      NaN        0
25200      NaN  116.938
```

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick! Thank you so much, very much appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe out of place here, but a small follow up question. Sorting this by the actual number of the index (0, 3600, 7200, 7600 etc...) seems not to work because it is created from 2 dictionaries and the number of the creation matters to the index? Or can I specify this somehow

Comment: @Micromegas hmm, so there are 2 dicts which influences the creation of a dataframe? really can't guess :-) I am okay if you edit the question and unaccept my answer or ask a new one. Whatever suits you :) feel free please

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just overwriting the index via df.index = ["..", "..."]